# Ubuntu-OS Compatible Tiff image format to Jpeg image format Convertion (.NET 5)

Tags: c#, image, .net-5, blazor-server-side, imagesharp

I want to Convert Tiff file/filestream into Jpeg file/filestream.
I am curretly developing a Blazor Server app with .NET 5 in Windows. But my Server is in Ubuntu OS. I am trying to display tiff image in webpage. In order to do that I am trying to convert my tiff images into jpeg which is supported by webpages. But I did not manage to do that.

Below I have described the processes that I tried so far:

For convertion I was using the following code.

```
public byte[] convertToJpeg(Byte[] tiffBytes)
{
    Byte[] jpegBytes;

    using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(tiffBytes))
    using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(inStream).Save(outStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        jpegBytes = outStream.ToArray();
    }
    return jpegBytes;
}
```

Unfortunately it runs perfectly fine in windows(my local PC's OS) but throws exception in Ubuntu(my server's OS).

> Message : The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception.     Data :
> System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal     InnerException :
> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Drawing.Common is not
> supported on non-Windows platforms. See
> https://aka.ms/systemdrawingnonwindows for more information.

After reading through [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only#reason-for-change). I found the reason of the exception. But my requrement prevents me from accessing the server's PC and installing **libgdiplus**. Also the server's PC will not be available in the open internet, will not access the internet and works only inside the internal network. Also it does not seem like a good soluton.

So, I tried following [Recommanded Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only#recommended-action) . Here is my code rewritten with ImageSharp.

```
public async Task<byte[]> ConvertToJpegAsync(byte[] inputByteArray)
{
    try
    {
        using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(inputByteArray))
        using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var image = await Image.LoadAsync(inputStream))
        {
            await image.SaveAsJpegAsync(outputStream);

            // Convert stream to byte[]
            return outputStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log Here
    }


    // Empty byte array
    return Enumerable.Empty<byte>().ToArray();
}
```

But I get the following error trying to open a tiff file:

> ex : SixLabors.ImageSharp.UnknownImageFormatException: Image cannot be
> loaded. Available decoders:
>
> - TGA : TgaDecoder
> - BMP : BmpDecoder
> - PNG : PngDecoder
> - GIF : GifDecoder
> - JPEG : JpegDecoder

In the end it seems nither ImageSharp nor SkiaSharp support Tiff. After further digging I found that ImageSharp does support it in it's [alpha build](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/issues/12#issuecomment-848084204). But I would reather not use alpa-build in my software.

So, in short a good implementation to convert Tiff to JPEG(or any web supported format such as bitmap, png) which works on the .NET 5 is what I am looking for.

- Thank you

Comment: The [Leadtools.Formats.Raster.Common NuGet package](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads/nuget?nuget_package=Leadtools.Formats.Raster.Common) works on Windows, Linux and other platforms. (Disclosure: I work for LEADTOOLS vendor). It supports many image formats, including TIFF and JPEG. The C# code is simply `rasterCodecs.Convert(inputTiffFileOrStream, outputJpegFileOrStream, RasterImageFormat.Jpeg411, 0, 0, 24, null);`. The `Convert` method works with both image files and streams. If you’d like to try it, get a free evaluation license from the page above.

Answer (score 0):

You code looks to be correct.

ImageSharp supports TIFF in its mainstream release. Which version did you reference, please try the latest from [NuGet.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SixLabors.ImageSharp/) (currently 2.1.1).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).